# Calling SharePoint Online REST API returns ? instead of umlaut

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

When I call SharePoint Online REST API to lookup a list item any values returns that contain umlauts are substituted for questions marks (?)

this is the URL i tried

e.g. `https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>/_api/lists/getbytitle('<listname>')/items?$select=Title,Id,Hashcode,Filename,Title/Title&$filter=(guid eq '62f0ff31-3d20-478a-a0d7-19f2d5709e71')`

e.g EU-Konformitätserklärung_de,en.pdf is returned as EU-Konformit?tserkl?rung_de,en.pdf

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This might help-https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/16634/rest-encoding-problem/

you will need to specify the encoding as utf-8